# Https Connection Android

Tags: java, android, ssl

I am doing a https post and I'm getting an exception of ssl exception Not trusted server certificate. If i do normal http it is working perfectly fine. Do I have to accept the server certificate somehow?

Comment: Can i get some sample implementation of the same

Comment: may this thread help, but i can not tell if it works will latest API : http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/1ac2b851e07269ba/c7275f3b28ad8bbc?#c7275f3b28ad8bbc

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I'm making a guess, but if you want an actual handshake to occur, you have to let android know of your certificate.  If you want to just accept no matter what, then use this pseudo-code to get what you need with the Apache HTTP Client:

```
SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry ();

schemeRegistry.register (new Scheme ("http",
    PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory (), 80));
schemeRegistry.register (new Scheme ("https",
    new CustomSSLSocketFactory (), 443));

ThreadSafeClientConnManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager (
    params, schemeRegistry);


return new DefaultHttpClient (cm, params);
```

CustomSSLSocketFactory:

```
public class CustomSSLSocketFactory extends org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
{
private SSLSocketFactory FACTORY = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory ();

public CustomSSLSocketFactory ()
    {
    super(null);
    try
        {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance ("TLS");
        TrustManager[] tm = new TrustManager[] { new FullX509TrustManager () };
        context.init (null, tm, new SecureRandom ());

        FACTORY = context.getSocketFactory ();
        }
    catch (Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public Socket createSocket() throws IOException
{
    return FACTORY.createSocket();
}

 // TODO: add other methods like createSocket() and getDefaultCipherSuites().
 // Hint: they all just make a call to member FACTORY 
}
```

FullX509TrustManager is a class that implements javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager, yet none of the methods actually perform any work, get a sample [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e537).

Good Luck!

Comment: Why is there the FACTORY variable??

Comment: Clarified in post.  You need FACTORY for the other override methods a SocketFactory needs to create a socket.

Comment: return FACTORY.createSocket(); is having problem. The created socket is giving null Pointer exception on execute(). Also, I noticed, there are 2 SocketFactory classes. 1. org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory and 2. javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory

Comment: Sorry, I think after little more digging, I found the problem, I have to implement the connectSocket() function, which by default returns null. Any idea on this?

Comment: Hi Nate, this looks like something helpful for my situation. But, I'm having some issues with making the CustomSSLSocketFactory. What class is it supposed to extend? Or what interface is is it supposed to implement? I've been experimenting with: javax.net.SocketFactory, javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory, org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory, all of which force implementation of other methods... So, in general, what are the namespaces of the classes used in your code? Thank you. :)

Comment: Cephron, CustomSSLSocketFactory implements LayeredSocketFactory and SocketFactory, in the org.apache.http.conn.scheme package.  At the time of this original post, HttpClient in Android was 4.0.x (not 4.1).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! But, in that case, I'm hitting the same wall as Codevalley. What do we put in the connectSocket() function? The FACTORY object doesn't seem to have anything to perform that function...

Comment: Does not work for me, gives me same Not trusted server certificate error.

Comment: how can i get this class `FullX509TrustManager`

Answer (score 94):

I copied the following code that came from [The Java Developers Almanac](https://web.archive.org/web/20061217061841/http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.net.ssl/TrustAll.html).

It simply doesn't check the certificate anymore.

> ```
> // always verify the host - dont check for certificate final static
> HostnameVerifier DO_NOT_VERIFY = new HostnameVerifier() {     public
> boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {         return true;
>   } };
>
> /**  * Trust every server - dont check for any certificate  */ private
> static void trustAllHosts() {     // Create a trust manager that does not
> validate certificate chains   TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new
> TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {         public
> java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {           return
> new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};      }
>
>       public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
>               String authType) throws CertificateException {      }
>
>       public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
>               String authType) throws CertificateException {      }   } };
>
>   // Install the all-trusting trust manager   try {       SSLContext sc =
> SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new
> java.security.SecureRandom());        HttpsURLConnection
>               .setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());     } catch (Exception e) {         e.printStackTrace();    } }
> ```

and

> ```
> HttpURLConnection http = null;
>
> if (url.getProtocol().toLowerCase().equals("https")) {
>     trustAllHosts();  HttpsURLConnection https = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();   https.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);   http
> = https; } else {     http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); }
> ```

Comment: This looks good! I'm using WebView, however, and only need to connect to a https server for test purposes. (The client can't provision one with a matching FQDN, nor can they test on http.) Is there any way to tackle this when using WebView? Do I just drop this code in the Activity where the WebView is and "it just works?" (Suspecting not … ??)

Comment: i'm trying to use that solution step by step and I'm getting such exception: 07-25 12:35:25.941: WARN/System.err(24383): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl
 in place where I'm trying to open connection... any idea why??

Comment: Hey I did as suggested by you but I am getting the exception as `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac` . I have also tried replacing `TLS` with `SSL` but it did not help. Please help me out, Thanks

Comment: While this is good during development phase, you should be aware of the fact that this allows anyone to MITM your secure connection by faking a random SSL certificate, which makes your connection not secure anymore. Have a look at [this question](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/SSLVerification_Android.aspx?display=Mobile) to see it made the right way, [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.net.ssl/GetCert.html) to see how to receive a certificate, and finally [this](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.security/AddCert.html) to learn how to add it to the keystore.

Comment: The above is just setup code, for the normal request. You can see an example at https://github.com/uscheller/EasyHttpClient/blob/master/src/EasyHttpClient.java#L194

Comment: Since it is published unter the Apache License, you are free to use it anywhere.

Comment: You should not use recommend or post this code. It is radically insecure. You should solve the actual problem.

Answer (score 4):

http://madurangasblogs.blogspot.in/2013/08/avoiding-javaxnetsslsslpeerunverifiedex.html

Courtesy Maduranga

When developing an application that uses https, your test server doesn't have a valid SSL certificate. Or sometimes the web site is using a self-signed certificate or the web site is using free SSL certificate. So if you try to connect to the server using Apache `HttpClient`, you will get a exception telling that the "peer not authenticated". Though it is not a good practice to trust all the certificates in a production software, you may have to do so according to the situation.
This solution resolves the exception caused by "peer not authenticated".

But before we go to the solution, I must warn you that this is not a good idea for a production application. This will violate the purpose of using a security certificate. So unless you have a good reason or if you are sure that this will not cause any problem, don't use this solution.

Normally you create a `HttpClient` like this.

`HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();`

But you have to change the way you create the HttpClient.

First you have to create a class extending `org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`.

```
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
         SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }
}
```

Then create a method like this.

```
public HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
     try {
         KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
         trustStore.load(null, null);

         SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
         sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

         HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
         HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
         HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

         SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
         registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
         registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

         ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

         return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         return new DefaultHttpClient();
     }
}
```

Then you can create the `HttpClient`.

`HttpClient httpclient = getNewHttpClient();`

If you are trying to send a post request to a login page the rest of the code would be like this.

```
private URI url = new URI("url of the action of the form");
HttpPost httppost =  new HttpPost(url);
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "user"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "password"));
try {
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream is = entity.getContent();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You get the html page to the InputStream. Then you can do whatever you want with the returned html page.

But here you will face a problem. If you want to manage a session using cookies, you will not be able to do it with this method. If you want to get the cookies, you will have to do it via a browser. Then only you will receive cookies.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a StartSSL or Thawte certificate, it will fail for Froyo and older versions. You can use a [newer version's CAcert repository](http://notwithoutmycode.com/post/trusting/startssl/or/thawte/certificates/in/older/android/versions/from/code) instead of trusting every certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Any of this answers didn't work for me so here is code which trust any certificates.

```
import java.io.IOException;

    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.security.KeyManagementException;
    import java.security.KeyStoreException;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
    import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
    import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

    import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
    import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
    import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
    import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
    import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
    import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
    import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.X509HostnameVerifier;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager;
    import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

    public class HttpsClientBuilder {
        public static DefaultHttpClient getBelieverHttpsClient() {

            DefaultHttpClient client = null;

            SchemeRegistry Current_Scheme = new SchemeRegistry();
            Current_Scheme.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
            try {
                Current_Scheme.register(new Scheme("https", new Naive_SSLSocketFactory(), 8443));
            } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpParams Current_Params = new BasicHttpParams();
            int timeoutConnection = 8000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(Current_Params, timeoutConnection);
            int timeoutSocket = 10000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(Current_Params, timeoutSocket);
            ThreadSafeClientConnManager Current_Manager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(Current_Params, Current_Scheme);
            client = new DefaultHttpClient(Current_Manager, Current_Params);
            //HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            //client.execute(httpPost);

         return client;
         }

    public static class Naive_SSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory
    {
        protected SSLContext Cur_SSL_Context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        public Naive_SSLSocketFactory ()
                throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException,
                KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException
        {
            super(null, null, null, null, null, (X509HostnameVerifier)null);
            Cur_SSL_Context.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new X509_Trust_Manager() }, null);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port,
                boolean autoClose) throws IOException
        {
            return Cur_SSL_Context.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket() throws IOException
        {
            return Cur_SSL_Context.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
        }
    }

    private static class X509_Trust_Manager implements X509TrustManager
    {

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: This code works fine with URL pattern - https://localhost:8443/webProject/YourService

Comment: The constructor SSLSocketFactory(null, null, null, null, null, X509HostnameVerifier) is undefined

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem with Android 2.x. I was struggling with this problem for a week until I came across the following question, which not only gives a good background of the problem but also provides a working and effective solution devoid of any security holes.

['No peer certificate' error in Android 2.3 but NOT in 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574870/no-peer-certificate-error-in-android-2-3-but-not-in-4)

Answer (score 1):

Sources that helped me get to work with my self signed certificate on my AWS Apache server and connect with HttpsURLConnection from android device:
[SSL on aws instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html) - amazon tutorial on ssl
[Android Security with HTTPS and SSL](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa) - creating your own trust manager on client for accepting your certificate
[Creating self signed certificate](https://github.com/coolaj86/nodejs-self-signed-certificate-example/blob/master/make-root-ca-and-certificates.sh) - easy script for creating your certificates

Then I did the following:

1. Made sure the server supports https (sudo yum install -y mod24_ssl)
2. Put this script in a file `create_my_certs.sh`:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> FQDN=$1
>
> # make directories to work from
> mkdir -p server/ client/ all/
>
> # Create your very own Root Certificate Authority
> openssl genrsa \
>   -out all/my-private-root-ca.privkey.pem \
>   2048
>
> # Self-sign your Root Certificate Authority
> # Since this is private, the details can be as bogus as you like
> openssl req \
>   -x509 \
>   -new \
>   -nodes \
>   -key all/my-private-root-ca.privkey.pem \
>   -days 1024 \
>   -out all/my-private-root-ca.cert.pem \
>   -subj "/C=US/ST=Utah/L=Provo/O=ACME Signing Authority Inc/CN=example.com"
>
> # Create a Device Certificate for each domain,
> # such as example.com, *.example.com, awesome.example.com
> # NOTE: You MUST match CN to the domain name or ip address you want to use
> openssl genrsa \
>   -out all/privkey.pem \
>   2048
>
> # Create a request from your Device, which your Root CA will sign
> openssl req -new \
>   -key all/privkey.pem \
>   -out all/csr.pem \
>   -subj "/C=US/ST=Utah/L=Provo/O=ACME Tech Inc/CN=${FQDN}"
>
> # Sign the request from Device with your Root CA
> openssl x509 \
>   -req -in all/csr.pem \
>   -CA all/my-private-root-ca.cert.pem \
>   -CAkey all/my-private-root-ca.privkey.pem \
>   -CAcreateserial \
>   -out all/cert.pem \
>   -days 500
>
> # Put things in their proper place
> rsync -a all/{privkey,cert}.pem server/
> cat all/cert.pem > server/fullchain.pem         # we have no intermediates in this case
> rsync -a all/my-private-root-ca.cert.pem server/
> rsync -a all/my-private-root-ca.cert.pem client/
> ```

3. Run `bash create_my_certs.sh yourdomain.com`
4. Place the certificates in their proper place on the server (you can find configuration in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf). All these should be set:
   SSLCertificateFile
   SSLCertificateKeyFile
   SSLCertificateChainFile
   SSLCACertificateFile
5. Restart httpd using `sudo service httpd restart` and make sure httpd started:
   Stopping httpd: [  OK  ]
   Starting httpd: [  OK  ]
6. Copy `my-private-root-ca.cert` to your android project assets folder
7. Create your trust manager:

   SSLContext SSLContext;

   CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
             InputStream caInput = context.getAssets().open("my-private-root-ca.cert.pem");
             Certificate ca;
             try {
               ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
             } finally {
               caInput.close();
             }

   ```
     // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
     String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
     KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
     keyStore.load(null, null);
     keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

     // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
     String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
     TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
     tmf.init(keyStore);

     // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
     SSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
     SSSLContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
   ```
8. And make the connection using HttpsURLConnection:

   HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   connection.setSSLSocketFactory(SSLContext.getSocketFactory());
9. Thats it, try your https connection.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the solution mentioned for httpClient above didn't worked for me. At the end I was able to make it work by correctly overriding the method when implementing the custom SSLSocketFactory class.

```
@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) 
                              throws IOException, UnknownHostException 
    {
    return sslFactory.createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return sslFactory.createSocket();
}
```

This is how it worked perfectly for me. You can see the full custom class and implementing on the following thread:
http://blog.syedgakbar.com/2012/07/21/android-https-and-not-trusted-server-certificate-error/

Answer (score 0):

I make this class and found

```
package com.example.fakessl;

import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;

import android.util.Log;

public class CertificadoAceptar {
    private static TrustManager[] trustManagers;

    public static class _FakeX509TrustManager implements
            javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager {
        private static final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = new X509Certificate[] {};

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                throws CertificateException {
        }

        public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
            return (true);
        }

        public boolean isServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
            return (true);
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return (_AcceptedIssuers);
        }
    }

    public static void allowAllSSL() {

        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
                .setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });

        javax.net.ssl.SSLContext context = null;

        if (trustManagers == null) {
            trustManagers = new javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[] { new _FakeX509TrustManager() };
        }

        try {
            context = javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e("allowAllSSL", e.toString());
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            Log.e("allowAllSSL", e.toString());
        }
        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context
                .getSocketFactory());
    }
}
```

in you code white this

```
CertificadoAceptar ca = new CertificadoAceptar();
ca.allowAllSSL();
HttpsTransportSE Transport = new HttpsTransportSE("iphost or host name", 8080, "/WS/wsexample.asmx?WSDL", 30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try something like this. This helped me

```
    SslContextFactory sec = new SslContextFactory();
    sec.setValidateCerts(false);
    sec.setTrustAll(true);

    org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient(sec);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use this method as your HTTPClient:

```
public static  HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
    try {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

        return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
}
```