# How to get HTTPS response

Tags: android, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a response from a https server using android sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478469/how-to-get-a-response-from-a-https-server-using-android-sdk)

hi,
I am doing a https post and I'm getting an exception of ssl exception Not trusted server certificate. If i do normal http it is working perfectly fine. Do I have to accept the server certificate somehow?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995514/https-connection-android

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012497/accepting-a-certificate-for-https-on-android

Comment: @dante: if you look at link posted by me it is exact duplicate, word by word.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478469/how-to-get-a-response-from-a-https-server-using-android-sdk

Comment: @Dante: I'm wondering how two people can think same words to ask question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

[Https Connection Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995514/https-connection-android)

Answer (score 0):

Can you access that HTTPS URL directly from your web browser? Or do you also get an error in that situation? Access it directly first to ascertain that the certificate is actually valid for that domain.

Comment: if you look at link posted by me it is exact duplicate, word by word.