# Not trusted certificate using ksoap2-android

Tags: android, soap, ssl, https, android-ksoap2

I'm using ksoap2-android to make a call to wcf service over SSL. I can get it to work without SSL, but now I want to make the call over SSL, but I've run in to some problems.

I'm using the HttpsTransportSE instead of HttpTransportSE, but I'm getting the error:
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate

How can I fix this?

Can I add the server certificate to the Keystore in Android to solve the problem?

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://example.com/Service/GetInformation";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetInformation";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://example.com";    
private static final String URL = "dev.example.com/Service.svc";

public static Result GetInformation()
{
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    PropertyInfo property = new PropertyInfo();
    property.name = "request";

    Request request =
        new Request("12", "13", "Ben");

    userInformationProperty.setValue(request);
    userInformationProperty.setType(request.getClass());
    request.addProperty(property);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Request",new Request().getClass());

    HttpsTransportSE transport = new HttpsTransportSE(URL, 443, "", 1000);

    //HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    transport.debug = true;

    try
    {
        transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);          
        return Result.FromSoapResponse((SoapObject)envelope.getResponse());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (XmlPullParserException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there is an easier way to do this instead of modifying HttpsServiceConnectionSE. You can install a fake trust manager as described in http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/1ac2b851e07269ba/c7275f3b28ad8bbc?lnk=gst&q=certificate and then call allowAllSSL() before you do any SSL communication/call to ksoap2. It will register a new default HostnameVerifier and TrustManager. ksoap2, when doing its SSL communication, will use the default ones and it works like a charm.

You can also put some more effort into this, make it (much) safer, and install certificates in an application local trust manager, I guess. I was in a safe network and not afraid of man-in-the-middle-attacks so I just did the first.

I found it necessary to use KeepAliveHttpsTransportSE like this `new KeepAliveHttpsTransportSE(host, port, file, timeout);`. The parameters go into a URL object, so e.g. to access a Jira installation it's something like `new KeepAliveHttpsTransportSE("host.whatever", 443, "/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2", 1000)`.

Sometimes its handy if you are new to the technology or the web service you like to use to play around with it in a J2SE environment instead of in the emulator or even on the device, but in the J2SE/ME ksoap2 library the (KeepAlive)HttpsTransportSE stuff is missing (I used ksoap2-j2se-full-2.1.2.jar). What you could do is to get the sources for the three classes HttpsTransportSE, KeepAliveHttpsTransportSE, and HttpsServiceConnectionSE from the Android spin-off ksoap2-android and put them into your J2SE project and use them. It worked for me and it became a productivity improvement to get the first steps right with an unknown and quite complex web service.

Comment: using your first solution is more or less the same as using no ssl

Answer (score 11):

To complement the answer of Vedran with some source code, sorry I can't comment.

The trustManager:

```
private static TrustManager[] trustManagers;

public static class _FakeX509TrustManager implements
        javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager {
    private static final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = new X509Certificate[] {};

    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
            throws CertificateException {
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
            throws CertificateException {
    }

    public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
        return (true);
    }

    public boolean isServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
        return (true);
    }

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return (_AcceptedIssuers);
    }
}

public static void allowAllSSL() {

    javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
            .setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

    javax.net.ssl.SSLContext context = null;

    if (trustManagers == null) {
        trustManagers = new javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[] { new _FakeX509TrustManager() };
    }

    try {
        context = javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e("allowAllSSL", e.toString());
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        Log.e("allowAllSSL", e.toString());
    }
    javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context
            .getSocketFactory());
}
```

The call at your method:

```
allowAllSSL();
HttpsTransportSE httpsTransport = new HttpsTransportSE(Server,443, URL, 1000);
```

Notes:

1. Server is the server url.
2. 443 is the default https port, you still have to specify a port since the constructor expects one.
3. URL the path to the WS operation
4. 1000 es the timeout

Which is constructed as:
[https://Server:443/URL]

Answer (score 1):

Works for me
KSOAP + Web service WCF with eclipse

```
private static SoapObject getBody(final SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope) throws Exception {
        if (soapEnvelope.bodyIn == null) {
            throw new Exception("soapEnvelope.bodyIn=null");
        }
        else if (soapEnvelope.bodyIn.getClass() == SoapFault.class) {
            throw new ExceptionLogic((SoapFault) soapEnvelope.bodyIn));
        }
        else {
            return (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
        }

    }

private static SoapSerializationEnvelope sendRequete(final SoapObject soapReq, final String classMappingName,
            final Class<?> classMapping, final int timeOutSpecial) {



        final SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;

        if (classMappingName != null) {
            soapEnvelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, classMappingName, classMapping);
        }

        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapReq);

        try {

            final HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Constante.urlWebService, timeOutSpecial);
            httpTransport.debug = BuildConfig.DEBUG;

            // Prod
            if (Constante.urlWebService.startsWith("https://")) {
                final List<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
                headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic "
                        + org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode((Constante.CERTIFICAT_LOGIN + ":" + Constante.CERTIFICAT_MDP).getBytes())));

                FakeX509TrustManager.allowAllSSL();
                httpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + "/" + soapReq.getName(), soapEnvelope, headerList);
            }
            // Test
            else {
                httpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + "/" + soapReq.getName(), soapEnvelope);
            }

            return soapEnvelope;
        }
        catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Erreur : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }



    private static class FakeX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
        private static TrustManager[] trustManagers;
        private final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = new X509Certificate[] {};

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return _AcceptedIssuers;
        }

        public static void allowAllSSL() {
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

                @Override
                public boolean verify(final String hostname, final SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            SSLContext context = null;
            if (trustManagers == null) {
                trustManagers = new TrustManager[] { new FakeX509TrustManager() };
            }
            try {
                context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                context.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
            }
            catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (final KeyManagementException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(final X509Certificate[] arg0, final String arg1) throws CertificateException {

        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) throws CertificateException {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes probably you can try this out

[Https Connection Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995514/https-connection-android#1000205)

There has been a bug that has been filed on Issue Tracker regarding this

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2388

Comment: You can try adding this before you make a server call

Comment: I've provided my current code in the post. I just can't see where and how I should put the code.

Comment: Most of the classes that you have provided in ur sample code are custom class. Were you able to succeed with the 1st approach ? here is another link that i found http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/62d856cdcfa9f16e/dd59b1998d23a660?lnk=gst&q=SSL+fake+cert#dd59b1998d23a660

Comment: I extended HttpsServiceConnectionSE with the code in your first link and now it works. Thanks for your help.