# KSoap2 HTTPS connection to web service

Tags: java, android, https, apache-axis, ksoap2

I'm using KSOAP2 to call to a web service. At first, I tried to work it without any kind of security (only HTTP) and the result was a success. Now I've added SSL security to my Web Service (it runs on an Apache Axis2), but I can't connect from my Android app by using KSOAP2. I've been searching around and the only answers I can get are the ones who tell me that I should trust all untrusted certificates (create a fake trustmanager):

[Not trusted certificate using ksoap2-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646121/not-trusted-certificate-using-ksoap2-android)

[KSOAP 2 Android with HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440062/ksoap-2-android-with-https)

And they paste always the same code:

```
private TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
new X509TrustManager() {
    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }
    public void checkClientTrusted(
        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
    }
    public void checkServerTrusted(
        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
    }
}
};
```

Which is not what I'm looking for. This answer, even if it works, it's just only a workaround and doesn't solve the problem, just avoids it.
What I want to know is if there is a way where you can modify the Android cacerts and add my untrusted certificate or just do something in order to avoid the solution I've just talked about. I don't want to create a new trustmanager if it could be possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with the Emulator don't use 10.0.2.2 for the server ip. For me it was not working.

Try to test your app on physical device (through Wifi)