# Ping server HTTPS using SOAP webservice in android

Tags: android, ssl, soap, truststore

I'm new to soap web service.I want to ping my server using https and i want to use soap.I referred the following links
[Not trusted certificate using ksoap2-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646121/not-trusted-certificate-using-ksoap2-android)
[KSOAP 2 Android with HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440062/ksoap-2-android-with-https)
but,it doesn't worked in my code. here is my code snippet

```
SSLConection.allowAllSSL();
HttpsTransportSE httpstransport = new HttpsTransportSE("myserver", 443, "rmo_t_json_v2.asmx", 1000);
httpstransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

Where I have to call `allowssl()`. what is third param in httpstransportSE.

Comment: Did you try [this solution](http://abhinavasblog.blogspot.com/2011/07/allow-untrusted-certificate-for-https.html) or [SO answer from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440062/ksoap-2-android-with-https)

Comment: Actually i didn't tried Ksoap2 sources file. I didn't get what exactly it is.One more thing i'm using trusted certificate not untrusted.