# Secure connection in android

Tags: android

In my android application i would like to use secure connection from client to server.Could anyone please suggest as how i can do it in android?

Please forward your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use SSL on the server.  If the key is self-signed you may need to include a public key within your app or something, then do whatever is need to get your secure connection working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using https (sockets and the like) like this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995514/https-connection-android)

Comment: Thanks Sriram for your quick response.I will try to implement this

Comment: @Remmyabhavan: Great! An upvote on my answer would be nice too though. But please let me know in case you run into trouble. It would be fun to debug!