# Certificate or Public key pinning slows down Web service response in Android

Tags: android, ssl, certificate, public-key, pinning

When I perform pinning (certificate / public key) on web services, in Android. I see that the time taken for the app to receive a response from the web service is close to double the time required without pinning.

This is because, the mechanism of pinning first establishes a connection to retrieve the certificates and validate them, and then goes for a second connection (not sure) to retrieve the response, from the server.

NOTE - In Android, it is advisable to use a connection on demand basis rather than a continuous connection to save power and bandwidth, on the device for the end user (unless required)

I would like to know if there is a way to optimise this sequential connections calls?

Example - https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/pubKeyPinningInAndroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/owasp/pubkeypin/PubKeyManager.java

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might help to provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are implementing the pinning.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667575/pinning-public-key-in-my-app