# HTTPS URL in Android webservice

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Https Connection Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995514/https-connection-android)

I am not able to work with HTTPS URL in Android webservice. It's working with HTTP but not with HTTPS. Please help me. I don't have any idea how to use HTTPS. Do I have to add any extra code? Please help me with that.

Comment: may be this could help u ,go through it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995514/https-connection-android

Comment: yes... for https the code should be added.