# Android user data encryption over web

Tags: android, security, encryption

In  my application, the user will be constantly uploading information on the website. For this I also need to pass the userId and password to the website for authentication.

What is the best way to encrypt this data and pass to the website? The website is using php.

I am looking for the best way to transfer encrypted data from android mobile to the website.

Rgds,
Sapan

Comment: 1st: accept more answers

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to have an SSL certificate on the web server. Because you'll also be in control of the client, you'd be able to self-sign without impacting end-user experience.

There are some questions on how to handshake and accept the certificate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012497/accepting-a-certificate-for-https-on-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995514/https-connection-android).