# Android SSL httpGet error 500 server denied the URL

Tags: android, ssl, webview, httpclient

I am trying to start a connection with a microsoft exchange server web access portal. The idea is my program initially opens a web view, and then continually refreshes the page using a BroadcastReceiver. I am aware that ordinarily, exchange web-based email access can be done through a protocol, but I'm trying this anyhow. The timing for the refresh works fine, but the problem is that although I open the connection with a WebView, I'm then doing the refresh with an HttpClient. I am passing the cookies after login from the WebView to the HttpClient successfully, and opening the connection for SSL, yet the web server is kicking back. This works fine in a browser, so I'm kinda lost.

EDIT: Ok, this is a more basic HTTP request question.  All of the code that handles the httpGet is setup in the constructor.  I don't even make a new HttpClient.  Now, This is a BroadcastReceiver, and it responds to a timed message every 60 seconds or so to make the request, but every time the code finishes, the thread seems to die, and every time the timer goes off, the blank constructor is called.  When coding an http GET request like this, do I need to be recreating the HttpClient every time? or is my using static variables that hold their value an ok way of doing it? The URL and cookies survive from one call to the next. What else am I missing?  The very first call to this thing doesn't seem to work either, so I still think it's that I'm doing SSL wrong.  Again, this site works just fine in a web browser, so I'm not emulating the request properly.

This is the constructor code:

```
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

     // RESTORE THE COOKIES!!!

    cookieJar = new BasicCookieStore();
    localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieJar);

    cookie = extras.getString("cookies");
    String[] cookieCutter = cookie.split(";");
    for (int i=0; i < cookieCutter.length; i++)
    {
        String[] values = cookieCutter[i].split("=");
        BasicClientCookie c = new BasicClientCookie(values[0], values[1]);
        c.setDomain(MAIL_WEB_SERVER);
        cookieJar.addCookie((Cookie)c);
    }
    HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;


    // Create local HTTP context


    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
    socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
    ThreadSafeClientConnManager mgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, params);
    httpClient.setCookieStore(cookieJar);

    // Set verifier     
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
```

And this is the refresh code:

```
        BasicCookieStore cookies = (BasicCookieStore)localContext.getAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE);
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
```

So where does this leave me? I get a Error Code: 500 Internal Server Error. The server denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL). Contact the server administrator. (12202)

I am moving the cookies over, and accepting all certificates...is there anything else from a browser session with an SSL connection and a login that I need to be passing along for the httpGet request?

Comment: I have thought that I need a new httpClient every single request, but this code doesn't even work the first time through.

Comment: oh, and I should mention I have printed logs of the cookies and I am correctly passing those through from the WebView to the httpClient.

Comment: I used to work on exchange server and it give me a headache, hope you find something helpful in there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407547/error-http-1-1-401-unauthorized-with-basic-authentication-in-android-ews-201

Comment: Ok, so it looks like all of this can be avoided if I use something along the lines of HtmlUnit or something called rhino...anyone have any experience with these?