# Android AsyncTask with JSON Parsing and Basic Authentication

Tags: android, android-asynctask, basic-authentication

I have a Rest web service, also service has a Basic Authentication. When I connect to the server, which asking me for a username and password. After that, I access a web service return a user about JsonArray. (username, birthday, age e.g.)

My purpose returning data parse at show the Textviews. I want to use AsyncTask Http request.

Can you give some examples of it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        try {
                postData(uri[0]);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        myTask2.cancel(true);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String url) {
        LinearLayouts();
    }
}

public static String postData(String url) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url);
    String responseString = "";

    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            if(inputStream != null)
                responseString = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                responseString = "Did not work!";
            JSONObject reader = null;
            JSONArray sys  = null;
            try {
                reader = new JSONObject(responseString);
                String res_metar = reader.getString("YOUR TAG");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //a = responseString;

        } else{
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

        // process execption
    }
    return responseString;
}

private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}
```

You should write it to top in your class.

```
private static RequestTask myTask2;
```

and add it to your mainactivity,

```
myTask2=(RequestTask)new RequestTask().execute(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

alican has already mentioned about asynctask.

Have a look at [Error "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized" with basic authentication in android - EWS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407547/error-http-1-1-401-unauthorized-with-basic-authentication-in-android-ews-201?rq=1) which contains information needed for basic authentication

Comment: Ok, I understood used to AsyncTask however I didn't know how to use Basic Authentication, example is mixed.

Comment: Following lines were there in above link : UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, pass);
 Header header = new BasicScheme().authenticate(credentials, mHttpRequest);
 mHttpRequest.addHeader(header);