# HTTPS programmatically on Android (trusts all certs)

Tags: android, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accepting a certificate for HTTPs on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012497/accepting-a-certificate-for-https-on-android)

Does anyone know where i might find a source on how this can be done? I've already tried doing my research but it bore no fruit

Comment: You might want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995514/https-connection-android
It't provide solution for both HttpClient and HttpConnection.