# Images not loading Via HTTPS

Tags: android, https

I am following this question to trust all hosts to load an image from my server.
[Https Connection Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995514/https-connection-android/1000205#1000205)

But it is not working in all devices.
I tried in OnePlus One and S5 and it is working.
But it is not working in MOTO G etc..

Its showing SSL handshake exception in those devices.

Couldnt find the reason why the same code works differently in different devices.

Comment: Have all the devices the same Android version? AFAIK Google modifies the default accepted SSL  certificates in each release. Maybe the mobilephones with older versions need to accept these certificates manually

Comment: No. s5 has 4.4.2 , OnePlus 5.0.2 and Moto 4.4.4.