# Glide image loader and HTTPS image link

Tags: android, android-glide

I am trying to load images from my server, but when image is loading I am getting:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Are there any configurations to set trust certificate for Glide or other settings to avoid this error?

Comment: Did you got any solution for this issue? Please share...

Answer (score 1):

You can accept self-signed https URL. For glide library, look here https://futurestud.io/blog/glide-module-example-accepting-self-signed-https-certificates.

Or

[Https Connection Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995514/https-connection-android)